# Skyrim: Hired Thugs are trying to kill me

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why has the innkeeper put a price on my head?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36160/why-has-the-innkeeper-put-a-price-on-my-head)

So I was in the city halfway between Solitude and Whiterun and I was doing a B&E. I stole a bunch of stuff and when I got outside there were Hired Thugs trying to kill me - not city guards.

I was not detected in my crimes. How did that happen? Is it part of a mission that just happened to start as I was breaking the law?

Comment: If not that, it's a possibility that it was just a random group of mercenaries. It happens to everyone at least once

Comment: _Who is it?_ **Goons.** _Who?_ **Hired goons.** _Hired goons?_

Comment: @Tullo +1 for recognising my mid-nineties Simpsons reference.

Comment: @Tullo but should be followed with *opens door anyway*

Comment: @Vemacitrin hired thugs he meant.

Comment: They're hired thugs.