# Can you steal from someone's house without being caught?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why has the innkeeper put a price on my head?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36160/why-has-the-innkeeper-put-a-price-on-my-head)

Every time I steal from someones house in Skyrim, they seem to know I did so and then they treat me like crap and send assassins to kill me.

When I steal I ensure I'm completely hidden, and I usually do it at night when everyone is asleep. My character is thief-based and has high sneak, lockpicking and 100 pickpocket (not that pickpocketing matters because I don't have this problem with pickpocketing).

So I've just been avoiding stealing lately, except for pickpocketing.

How can I burgle someone's house undetected?

Comment: There must be something you're not telling us/noticing yourself.. if you're hidden, you should be able to steal no problem.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36160/why-has-the-innkeeper-put-a-price-on-my-head It's the same awnser

Comment: It's not the same answer, or should not be.