# Where can I find Ainethach?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

This guy hired thugs to kill me. I read the contract and the guy was called Ainethach. Where can I find him?

Comment: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hired_Thug and http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ainethach ; looks like you might have wronged him in some way, his location is on the wiki

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36160/why-has-the-innkeeper-put-a-price-on-my-head

Comment: Also related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/198112/orgnar-has-sent-thugs-after-me-wtf

Answer (score 3):

He should be in Karthwasten which is in The Reach.

Source: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ainethach

Comment: False: He's not in the town Markarth, but in the hold of Markarth. The hold is called the Reach, which you should be changing so we won't get confused.